# Mysql or flat file or php get request JSON

Tags: php, json, model-view-controller, scalability

Question about best practices / scaling of the web application.

What would be the best way to access application settings on which all users rely and can not modify. Data needs to be served in JSON, application is written in PHP / JS.

Have 3 ways in my mind:

1. Serve json as a php get request which will call final method

   ```
   final function get_requestJSON() 
   {
       return json_encode(array(.... ));
   }
   ```
2. Serve is as a flat file with JSON written in it and use file_get_contents
3. Store it in text format in MySQL backed and access it directly with a model.

Which one of those would be considered fastest?

Any thoughts?

- j

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about speed in this case (unless you know that the wrong solution is unacceptably slow) and instead think of your requirements.  This is especially true because if you are issuing server calls through a client, there's going to be a latency anyway that will likely dwarf the time for this operation.

Also, the scenarios are not mutually exclusive.  You can store things in a database, and use JSON as your protocol for sending things back and forth (for example).

I recommend you instead think about all the things you can see doing with this information, both now and in the future, and let that guide you towards a decision.

Answer (score 0):

Taking all into consideration, php library with methods is the best solution for me. Thanks for the info though.